# svn head revision from a remote repository in windows batch file - the system cannot find the file specified

Tags: windows, batch-file, svn, command-line

How do I get a SVN revision number of a remote repository in a windows batch file ? I want to check for a condition when the user enters blank i have to get HEAD revision.

I'm using the following snippet to get the revision number. Although the for loop returns all the necessary information w.r.t remote SVN server location including the revision number. Still the batch file throws
**The system cannot find the file specified** and the variable %SVN_VERSION%
still remains empty.

In the below mentioned code, the %SVN_PATH% points to the remote server URL

```
set /p "SVN_VERSION=Please specify the SVN Revision number. For HEAD revision press Enter"
    if "%SVN_VERSION%" =="" (
    for /f "delims=: tokens=1,2" %%a in ('svn info %SVN_PATH%') do (
              if "%%a"=="Revision:" (
                set /a SVN_VERSION=%%b
            )
        )
    )
```

Thanks

Comment: what show this? `svn info %SVN_PATH% | findstr /ic:"Revision:"`

Comment: Also you can use directly [`svnversion` command: Summarize the local revision(s) of a working copy.](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnversion.re.html)

Comment: 1. you should reset your variable by `set SVN_VERSION=` before the `set /p` command, as this does not clear a previous number; 2. is the location of `svn.exe` contained in the system's `%path%` variable, or in which directory do you run your script?

Comment: @Paul: Actually the Revision is returned in the for loop step, but somehow the value is not being set to the %SVN_VERSION% variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, you can directly obtain revision with [`svnversion command`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnversion.re.html).

```dos
@echo off
set /p "SVN_VERSION=Please specify the SVN Revision number. For HEAD revision press Enter"
if "%SVN_VERSION%"=="" (
    for /f %%a in ('svnversion') do set "SVN_VERSION=%%a"
)
exit /b 0
```

**Edit**

[Here it is well explained how to use the command `svnversion`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1828141/4070433)

**Edit**

According to your comments and trying to guess in your mind, the following  command should work if you know the remote_url

```dos
@echo off

rem Edit remote_url
set /p "remote_url=Please specify the SVN repo url http://....." || goto:EOF

set /p "SVN_VERSION=Please specify the SVN Revision number. For HEAD revision press Enter"

if "%SVN_VERSION%"=="" (
    for /f "delims=: tokens=1,2" %%a in ('svn info %remote_url%') do (
        if "%%a"=="Revision" ( set SVN_VERSION=%%b )
    )
)
exit /b 0
```

**Edit**

This should also work since I have seen what should be the input

```dos
@echo off

set /p "SVN_VERSION=Please specify the SVN Revision number. For HEAD revision press Enter"

if "%SVN_VERSION%"=="" (
    for /f "tokens=1,2" %%a in ('svn info %SVN_PATH% ^|findstr /ic:"Revision"') do set SVN_VERSION=%%b
)
exit /b 0
```

Explanation:
Your mistake was with `delims=:` since `:` is not part of the `tokens` the comparison came wrong.
Also, the default `delims` is space, so don't need to specify a delims here since the line are splited in two parts.

Comment: How does the svnversion command know to look for that specific remote repository  ?

Comment: No, this wouldn't work because I need the information from the remote repository. I do not have a local working copy yet.

Comment: %SVN_PATH% - user defined variable which points to the remote SVN Server URL. Similar to the variable you have defined %remote_url%

Comment: Removing colon worked. Really don't understand how did I missed it. Thanks for helping me out