# python version 3.4 does not support a 'ur' prefix

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some python code writen in an older version of python(2.x) and I struggle to make it work. I'm using python 3.4

```
_eng_word = ur"[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9'.]*"
```

(it's part of a tokenizer)

Comment: Did you want to make this work on *both Python 2 and 3*? Or only on Python 3?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I only need it to work on python 3.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

http://bugs.python.org/issue15096

Title:  Drop support for the "ur" string prefix
When PEP 414 restored support for explicit Unicode literals in Python 3, the "ur" string prefix was deemed to be a synonym for the "r" prefix.

So, use 'r' instead of 'ur'

Comment: It is not a synonym in Python 2.7 however.

Comment: Which isn't relevant to the OP, they're trying to make it work in 3.4.  My read is that if they wanted 3.4 and 2.7 they would say so.

Comment: It was removed because the behaviour of the Python 2 `ur'...'` raw string literals could not be reproduced.

Comment: Hrm, I interpreted this as having to work on *both*. I've asked for clarification.

Comment: If OP wants both, I'll remove my answer - you know what happens when we assume.

Comment: It's the implicit assumptions that trip us up, of course. :-P

Comment: Yet another place that PY2 and PY3 have fundamentally different interpretations of what it means to have certain bytes/characters/glyphs in source files. PY3 is more disciplined and less ambiguous, but there aren't always neat, concise ways to have source files that run identically in both. Compatibility libraries like six do not seem to address this situation.

Answer (score 17):

Indeed, Python 3.4 only supports `u'...'` (to support code that needs to run on both Python 2 and 3) and `r'....'`, but not both. That's because the semantics of how `ur'..'` works in Python 2 are different from how `ur'..'` would work in Python 3 (in Python 2, `\uhhhh` and `\Uhhhhhhhh` escapes still are processed, in Python 3 a `r'...' string would not).

Note that in *this specific case* there is no difference between the raw string literal and the regular! You can just use:

```
_eng_word = u"[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9'.]*"
```

and it'll work in both Python 2 and 3.

For cases where a raw string literal does matter, you could *decode* the raw string from `raw_unicode_escape` on Python 2, catching the `AttributeError` on Python 3:

```
_eng_word = r"[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9'.]*"
try:
    # Python 2
    _eng_word = _eng_word.decode('raw_unicode_escape')
except AttributeError:
    # Python 3
    pass
```

If you are writing Python 3 code *only* (so it doesn't have to run on Python 2 anymore), just drop the `u` entirely:

```
_eng_word = r"[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9'.]*"
```

Comment: I upvoted you for the `raw_unicode_string` encoding idea, but your code will produce different results between Python 2 and Python 3.

Comment: @itsadok: it's close enough for these purposes. You could also use a regular string, double escaped backslashes then decode as `unicode_escape`: `_eng_word = '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9'.]*'; _eng_word.replace(r'\\', r'\\\\').decode('unicode_escape')`, this is the approach that `six` uses.

Comment: @itsadok: and take into account that `\uhhhh` patterns have meaning in `re`  *too*. So even if in Python 3, you end up with `\\uhhhh` (escaped) Unicode sequences, they still have the same meaning in the regular expression as if you had passed in the literal Unicode codepoint.

Answer (score 9):

This table compares (some of) the different string literal prefixes in Python 2(.7) and 3(.4+):
[image]

As you can see, in Python 3 there's no way to have a literal that doesn't process escapes, but does process unicode literals. To get such a string with code that works in both Python 2 and 3, use:

```
br"[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9'.]*".decode('raw_unicode_escape')
```

Actually, your example is not very good, since it doesn't have any unicode literals, or escape sequences. A better example would be:

```
br"[\u03b1-\u03c9\u0391-\u03a9][\t'.]*".decode('raw_unicode_escape')
```

In python 2:

```
>>> br"[\u03b1-\u03c9\u0391-\u03a9][\t'.]*".decode('raw_unicode_escape')
u"[\u03b1-\u03c9\u0391-\u03a9][\\t'.]*"
```

In Python 3:

```
>>> br"[\u03b1-\u03c9\u0391-\u03a9][\t'.]*".decode('raw_unicode_escape')
"[α-ωΑ-Ω][\\t'.]*"
```

Which is really the same thing.