# How to fix the invalid syntax error for punctuation removal by using regex?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am trying to remove the punctuation (except - & .) by using regex. Input for the punctuation removal is preprocessed token. However, I am getting a syntax error (SyntaxError: invalid syntax) for my code. Where do I need to modify to fix the syntax error?

I have tried to fix it by changing the regex. I am relatively new with regex. Some recommendation might help me to fix the error or to identify my mistakes.

My code is as follows:

```
regex = re.compile('[%s]' % re.escape(string.punctuation))

token_without_punctuation = []

for x in tokenized_doc1:
    y = []
    for token in x:
        tokens = regex.sub(ur"\p{P}(?<![\-.])", "", token)
          y.append(tokens)

    token_without_punctuation.append(y)

print(token_without_punctuation)
```

Input for my code is as follows:

```
[['The', 'intelligent', 'directory', 'enquiry', 'assistant', '(', 'YPA', ')', 'project', 'is', 'an', 'example', '(', 'going', 'back', 'quite', 'a', 'few', 'years', 'now', '...', ')', 'where', 'the', 'extraction', 'of', 'information', 'from', 'partially', 'structured', 'data', 'together', 'with', 'engineering', 'issues', 'played', 'major', 'roles', 'in', 'making', 'the', 'YPA', 'a', 'usable', 'online', 'system', '.'], ['I', 'am', 'developing', 'techniques', 'that', 'allow', 'the', 'extraction', 'of', 'conceptual', 'information', 'from', 'document', 'collections', 'and', 'the', 'utilization', 'of', 'such', 'knowledge', 'in', 'retrieval', 'tasks', '.'], ['The', 'type', 'of', 'documents', 'can', 'range', 'from', 'Web', 'pages', 'to', 'newspaper', 'articles', 'or', 'other', 'forms', 'of', 'vaguely/partially', 'structured', 'data', '.']]
```

The error is as follows

```
  File "<ipython-input-108-0c96ff0d8e79>", line 10
    tokens = regex.sub(ur"\p{P}(?<![\-.])", "", token)
                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It would be really great if someone help to identify my mistakes.

Additional information:

I have also tried with the below code.

```
tokens = regex.sub(u'', token)
        if not token == u'':
```

Above mentioned lines fix the error but it removes all the punctuations.  I have also tried with `tokens = regex.sub(u'\p{P}(?<![\-.])', token)`. In that case, I am getting another error which is as follows,

```
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

How can I remove punctuations (except. and -) without getting an error?

Comment: `ur'<string>'` is a syntax error in Python 3. You can have `u'<string>'` and `r'<string>'`, but not combined.

Comment: Check here https://stackoverflow.com/a/26063984/10418812

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `regex` variable in your code is a compiled `re` object. You are later using it as a PyPi `regex` module reference, you are even using a regex that only PyPi `regex` module will "understand". It is not at all correct.

Note that to remove all ambiguity between `re` and `regex` I suggest renaming `regex` variable to `punct_rx`.

Now, you form a punctuation regex using `'[%s]' % re.escape(string.punctuation)` code. You get `` [\!\"\#\$\%\&\'\(\)\*\+\,\-\.\/\:\;\<\=\>\?\@\[\\\]\^_\`\{\|\}\~] `` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/ES3uyf/1)). Probably, it makes sense to remove `-` and `.` when you build the regex. Change that code to `re.compile('[%s]' % re.escape(string.punctuation.replace(".", "").replace("-", "")))`, and you will get a `` [\!\"\#\$\%\&\'\(\)\*\+\,\/\:\;\<\=\>\?\@\[\\\]\^_\`\{\|\}\~] `` pattern ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/ES3uyf/2)).

Then, all that remains is fix the replacement code as `tokens = punct_rx.sub("", token)`.

See the full fix:

```
import re, string

tokenized_doc1 = [['The', 'intelligent', 'directory', 'enquiry', 'assistant', '(', 'YPA', ')', 'project', 'is', 'an', 'example', '(', 'going', 'back', 'quite', 'a', 'few', 'years', 'now', '...', ')', 'where', 'the', 'extraction', 'of', 'information', 'from', 'partially', 'structured', 'data', 'together', 'with', 'engineering', 'issues', 'played', 'major', 'roles', 'in', 'making', 'the', 'YPA', 'a', 'usable', 'online', 'system', '.'], ['I', 'am', 'developing', 'techniques', 'that', 'allow', 'the', 'extraction', 'of', 'conceptual', 'information', 'from', 'document', 'collections', 'and', 'the', 'utilization', 'of', 'such', 'knowledge', 'in', 'retrieval', 'tasks', '.'], ['The', 'type', 'of', 'documents', 'can', 'range', 'from', 'Web', 'pages', 'to', 'newspaper', 'articles', 'or', 'other', 'forms', 'of', 'vaguely/partially', 'structured', 'data', '.']]
punct_rx = re.compile('[%s]' % re.escape(string.punctuation.replace(".", "").replace("-", "")))
token_without_punctuation = []

for x in tokenized_doc1:
    y = []
    for token in x:
        tokens = punct_rx.sub("", token)
        y.append(tokens)
    token_without_punctuation.append(y)

print(token_without_punctuation)
```

See the[Python demo](https://ideone.com/gJM5yD).

Comment: @ Wiktor Stribiżew, Thanks a lot for the useful explanation and solution.