# Python SyntaxError: invalid syntax when implementing bbcodepy

Tags: python, bbcode

I got [bbcodepy](https://github.com/vishnevskiy/bbcodepy) and I'm allowed to modify it, but I can't import it in my main.py. I keep getting a SyntaxError and I don't really know what's wrong with the code because I didn't write it. I just want to tinker around a little bit and see if I can get it to fill my needs.
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoK2w.png)'s an image pointing me in the direction of the syntax error. But I noticed the same code is written on the same line and I don't get the SyntaxError for that. Here's the code:

```
_URL_RE = re.compile(ur'''\b((?:([\w-]+):(/{1,3})|www[.])(?:(?:(?:[^\s&()]|&amp;|&quot;)*(?:[^!"#$%&'()*+,.:;<=>?@\[\]^`{|}~\s]))|(?:\((?:[^\s&()]|&amp;|&quot;)*\)))+)''')
```

The problem appears to be "**[^\s&()]**" but only the second one, not the first one. If you look closely in the code you'll see that the same thing appears twice, but I only get the SyntaxError on the second appearance. Someone enlighten me, please. I've been trying to find a decent BBCode parser for Python for a couple of days now and I believe this is the one I can modify to my needs. I can't seem to get [bbcode](https://github.com/dcwatson/bbcode) to work as I want it to, so I'm trying this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Python version 3.4 and above does not support a 'UR' prefix.

You need to execute your code with Python 2.7, or change to line into:

```
_URL_RE = re.compile(r'''\b((?:([\w-]+):(/{1,3})|www[.])(?:(?:(?:[^\s&()]|&amp;|&quot;)*(?:[^!"#$%&'()*+,.:;<=>?@\[\]^`{|}~\s]))|(?:\((?:[^\s&()]|&amp;|&quot;)*\)))+)''')
```

See also: [python version 3.4 does not support a 'ur' prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26063899)

Note: consider avoiding triple-quoted string because if you insert a newline, it can change the meaning of the regex (unless it is compiled in VERBOSE mode).

Comment: @DomniusCarswell, you are welcome. You can upvote/accept this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: There's a 5 minute wait until I can accept the answer, I sure will. Don't worry