# How to get PyInstaller to embed SVN Working Copy properties in the generated executable?

Tags: python, svn, pyinstaller

I am using Python **3.5.2** and PyInstaller **3.2** to turn a small **PyQt5** application into a standalone utility for internal use.  **PyInstaller** is necessary because most of the team hasn't installed Python3.

I would like to put the Subversion properties of the WC from which the utility is generated into the utility's `Help->About` dialog, but I'm struggling to figure out a reasonable approach for doing this.

If I were using a different build environment I would define a template file and have TortoiseSVN's SubWCRev generate a source file as a pre-build step.  At the moment however the `"build"` of my utility is the one-step process of invoking PyInstaller on a modified spec file.  I'd prefer to keep it this way.

I suspect that it is possible to write a custom hook for PyInstaller that will get the required properties from the working copy, (equivalents of `WCRANGE`, `WCMODS` and `WCMIXED`, probably using **pysvn**), and embed them as properties of the generated `exe`.  Has anyone done this, or is this approach completely wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1812153/960558) for good pythonic-way and maybe the whole topic

Comment: @LazyBadger The problem with the approach as outlined by the solution that you linked to is that the revision will be the revision of the particular `__init__.py` file.  TortoiseSVN's SubWCRev program will look for the highest and lowest version of all the files in the working copy, hence you get a range of revision numbers rather than the single revision of a particular file, and I'm particularly looking to replicate that behaviour.

Comment: @Wasi Are there guidelines for standard formatting of questions?  It's not obvious to me why your formatting is better than the original plain text.

Comment: [Check out this link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: @PeterDu - it's not a problem (at least for me) to commit file in every revision

Comment: @PeterDu - and your OS and used SVN tool is ...?

Comment: @lazybadger It's windows 7 & TortoiseSVN most of the time. I think that I can extract the properties with pysvn if I have the opportunity to run python in the context of pyinstaller. The question then is how to make the result accessible to the application.

Comment: Why not run SubWCRev in post-commit hook and write proper file, which you can `import NAME` in your code?

Comment: Another opportunities - 1) hack [python-versioneer](https://blog.mozilla.org/warner/2012/01/31/version-string-management-in-python-introducing-python-versioneer/) in order to work with SVN (here pysvn will be needed) 2) sync SVN-repo with Git-clone and use Verioneer as is

Comment: @lazybadger yes something like the suggestion with the post commit hook. I'm thinking that i can do it as part of the pyinstaller build rather than post commit. I'll try along those lines tomorrow and let you know how I went.

Comment: The `.spec` file is actually a python script. You can add a piece of code before the Analysis block to extract the information from SVN and write it  in a text file. You can then add that to the build at the datas block.

Comment: @Repiklis that seems promising.  Will report back tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the tips. The direction described by [@Repiklis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3837382/repiklis) provided a good solution.
I've added the following code at the top of my .spec file for PyInstaller

```
import json
import os
import pysvn

os.remove('versioninfo.json')

c = pysvn.Client()
entry = c.info('.')
statuses = c.status('.')

mods = [{'Path': s.path,
            'CommitRevision': s.entry.commit_revision.number,
            'UpdateRevision': s.entry.revision.number,
            'Kind': str(s.entry.kind),
            'Status': str(s.text_status if
                            s.entry.kind == pysvn.node_kind.file
                        else
                            s.prop_status)
        } for s in statuses if (
    s.text_status != pysvn.wc_status_kind.none
    and 
    s.text_status != pysvn.wc_status_kind.unversioned
    and 
    s.text_status != pysvn.wc_status_kind.ignored
)]

version = {'URL': entry.url, 'Source': mods}

with open('versioninfo.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(version, fp=fp, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
```

Later there is

```
a = Analysis(...
             datas=[..., ('versioninfo.json', '.')]
             ...
            )
```

Finally, the json file is loaded in the `Help->About` dialog, and presented to the user.

Thanks everyone.